# Can't find or create a .env file

Tags: visual-studio

So I am working on a website and when I was looking through my files in my IDE I could not find my .env file, yet when I look it up on my command prompt its there. I also have a json file that appears to make one. Why can't I see my file in my Visual Studio IDE and how can I make a new .env file?

I've tried using the cygwin terminal and windows command prompt with the cp .env.example .env command yet it says that no such .env.example exists.

```
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
```

This is what my post create project has, which I've seen should have a .env in some form.

I expect the file to be visible but not needed since it's in the gitignore.

Comment: When you type `ls` in your terminal what files are listed ?

Comment: it shows: 745 .env, along with all the other files I have like .gitignore for example

Comment: I guess your IDE doesn't like files that start with a dot.